# Pressed and non-pressed thunderbird buttons indistinguishable in dark theme

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, themes, thunderbird

I prefer dark themes for my applications.

Unfortunately, in Thunderbird, when I select a dark GTK3 theme in the system settings, the "quick filter" buttons that are pressed are not distinguishable anymore. Here is a screenshot of the buttons with the default and the breeze-dark theme.

Default (light) theme

[image]

The same after switching to the Breeze-Dark theme (note that "Sender" is selected, but "Recipients" is not, but this is almost invisible. In contrast, "Quick Filter" (top left) is clearly seen)

[image]

I have tried many different dark themes but none seems to work reasonably.

Is there a way to fix this? BTW, this refers to a Kubuntu 20.04 installation, in case this matters.

Comment: what's wrong with a light themed OS?

Comment: Please file a bug report against both the theme and against Thunderbird. The developers of both did not intend this behavior.